# Display array content in column dynamically using perl

Tags: arrays, perl, loops

I would like to display array contents in column view. For example: My array contains 9 values as below:

```
@numbers = ("One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine");
```

I want display the values in 2 columns as below:

```
One      Two
Three    Four
Five     Six
Seven    Eight
Nine
```

I can use tables and display as shown above but i want to do the same thing dynamically using loops for a very large array.

Can anyone please help me with this.

Thank You

Avinesh

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using splice, you can also modify number of columns:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @numbers = ("One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine");
my $numcols = 2;
while (@numbers) {
  print join("\t", splice(@numbers,0, $numcols)), "\n";
}
```

Comment: The columns are not justified in a few places. What can I do to properly align and justify the columns?

Comment: @OneFace, for awesome results, you need to calculate the longest cell in each column and use space padding instead of tab characters.

Answer (score 5):

A simple math trick would also do this. Check if the array index is divisible by 2. If yes, print a newline as long as it is not the 0th element.

```
my @numbers = ("One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine");

foreach my $i (0..$#numbers) {
  print "\n" if ($i%2 == 0 and $i != 0);
  print $numbers[$i] . "\t";
}
```

Comment: This is really nice. it may help me in my other applications.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something printable instead of tabs,

```
push @data, '' if @data % 2 != 0;

my $col1_width = 0;
my $col2_width = 0;
for (my $i=0; $i<@data; ) {
   $col1_width = length($data[$i]) if length($data[$i]) > $col1_width; ++$i;
   $col2_width = length($data[$i]) if length($data[$i]) > $col2_width; ++$i;
}

my $format = "%-${col1_width}s  %-${col2_width}s\n";
printf($format, splice(@data, 0, 2))
   while @data;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should harness the power of [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org/), use the module [Data::Tabulator](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aTabulator). It does exactly what you need, *"Create a table (two-dimensional array) from a list (one-dimensional array)"*.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **map**:

```
map { print $numbers[$_] . ( ($_ + 1) % $numcols == 0 ? "\n" : "\t" ) } 0..$#numbers;
```

or:

```
@numbers = map { $numbers[$_] . ( ($_ + 1) % $numcols == 0 ? "\n" : "\t" ) } 0..$#numbers;
print @numbers;
```

Comment: This looks something to me. I am definatly going to try this out. Thanks alot.